# Export more than 50 Kinds from Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

We are attempting to use the new [datastore export](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities) to export more than 50 different entity kinds. Currently this is not possible in a single backup request. Ideally the backups would all end up in the same Cloud Storage bucket (split by kind).

Things we've tried already:

- **Exporting everything (not specifying entity kinds to filter by):** This process takes over 4 hours to complete and results in all entity kinds being combined together in a single folder rather than one folder by kind.
- **Splitting the export into multiple chunks:** When we try and export multiple different entities into the same bucket, we get the error *Path already exists: /BUCKET_NAME/2018-08-21T09:37:53/2018-08-21T09:37:53.overall_export_metadata*

Comment: Did you try using a different, per-kind namespace path as per [Set up your environment](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/export-import-entities#set_up_your_environment): `BUCKET="YOUR_BUCKET_NAME[/NAMESPACE_PATH]"`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Will give that a try now.

Comment: @drei01, did that solution work for you?

Comment: This suggested solution didn't work. We asked Google to increase the limit in the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 50 kind limit is arbitrarily set by Google. We raised a support ticket with them and they were able to increase the limit for our account.